# MVC3 How to disable/enable ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have if condition and I want to disable or enable my actionLink button.

How would I do it?

`@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = @Model.Id})`

Thanks,

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you know on the server side that the link is not available then just render a message that the action is not available:

```
@if(condition)
{
   @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = @Model.Id})
}
else
{
   <text>Action is not available</text>
}
```

Otherwise you can only disable a link with

- CSS: [Disable link using css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091168/disable-a-link-using-css)
- JS: [How to enable or disable an anchor using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164635/how-to-enable-or-disable-an-anchor-using-jquery)

To make it work cross-browser: [Should the HTML Anchor Tag Honor the Disabled Attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000927/should-the-html-anchor-tag-honor-the-disabled-attribute)

Answer (score 22):

To disable a "a" tag you can do:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = @Model.Id}, new { onclick = "javascript:return false;" })
```

Or you can use JQuery:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = @Model.Id}, new { class = "linkdisabled" })
```

CSS:

```
.linkdisabled{
   cursor:text;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$function(){
    $(".linkdisabled").click(function(){
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, nice solution.. but is there any way to make the text non-click able. Now it appears as a link but its not going anywhere. So is there any way to change its appearance. Thanks

Comment: You can add a style attribute or use a css class to do that:

Answer (score 6):

A little late to the party, but in case anyone else stumbles across this...
If your project is bootstrapped, you can do this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = @Model.Id}, new { @class = "btn btn-default disabled" })
```

or

```
@{
    bool btnDisabled = // Logic here;
}

@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = @Model.Id}, new { @class = "btn btn-default " + @btnDisabled ? "disabled" : "" })
```

Comment: Adding true/false to the @class didn't work for me. I tested it by adding string "disabled" or adding empty string when button supposed to be enabled and it worked fine. With "disabled" added it would be my preferred solution and I would upvote this answer.

Comment: @Mariusz I edited the second part of my answer, just didn't finish the thought when I was writing it. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Exactly. Thanks and upvoted your answer:-)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can create your own UI of type MvcHtmlString

```
public static MvcHtmlString MyActionLink(this HtmlHelper helper, bool isClickable, string altText, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, object htmlAttributes = null) 
{
    // some logic with isClickale parameter here
    if(isClickable == false)
    {}

    return new MvcHtmlString(helper.ToHtmlString());
}
```

and use it in your View

```
@Html.MyActionLink( // some parameters here )
```

But I have never try it. Try find something about **MvcHtmlString** on Google.

Answer (score 1):

Someone might find this useful, I once solved a similar problem by turning @Html.ActionLink into an input `<input type="submit" id = "submit" />`
and then you make it work as a link using javascript:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#submit').click(function () {
            if(condition){
               //sth (not working as a link)
            }
            else
            {
                window.location.href = "/home/thanks"; //working as a link
            }
        })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@if(condition)
{
   @Html.ActionLink("Delete", null, null, new { @class = "btn btn-danger",@style= "cursor: not-allowed;", @onclick = "return false;" })
}
else
{
   @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ID }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary", @onclick = "return true;" })
}



@if(condition)
{
   @Html.ActionLink("Delete", null, null, new { href = "#",@class = "btn btn-danger",@style= "cursor: not-allowed;" })
}
else
{
   @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ID }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**